# Why is it sufficient to check at one point on the orbit to determine the hyperbolicity?

Tags: dynamical-systems

In this Wikipedia entry on [hyperbolic sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_set) of dynamical systems, on the examples section, it was asserted that "more generally, a periodic orbit of $f$ with period $n$ is hyperbolic if and only if $Df^n$ at any point of the orbit has no eigenvalue with absolute value 1, and it is enough to check this condition at a single point of the orbit." I am confused of why it is sufficient to only check at one point.

Comment: Because the Jacobians $Df^n$ at the orbit points are conjugate to each other, as they are cyclic permutations of the product of the single Jacobians $Df$ at the orbit points.

Comment: Thanks. I see it now.